# Mock response value in custom Ajax function using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, mocking, jestjs

We replaced axios with a custom ajax function to avoid Promises and any features that aren't supported by IE11.

```
/* _utility.js */

export const ajaxGet = ( config ) => {
    const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const defaultConfig = Object.assign( {
        url: '',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: ( response ) => {},
    }, config );

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
            if ( httpRequest.status >= 200 && httpRequest.status < 300 ) {
                defaultConfig.success( JSON.parse( httpRequest.responseText ) );
            }
        }
    };

    httpRequest.open( 'GET', defaultConfig.url, true );
    httpRequest.send();
};
```

This is used in React JS the following way:

```
/* AggregationPageContent */

export class AggregationPageContent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { restUrl, termId } = tlsAggregationPage;

        ajaxGet( {
            url: `${ restUrl }/category/${ termId }?page=${ this.state.page }`,
            success: ( response ) => {
                this.setState( {
                    data: response,
                    page: 1,
                }
            },
        } );
    }
}
```

While working with axios, the response was mocked this way:

```
/* AggregationPage.test.js */

import { aggregationData } from '../../../stories/aggregation-page-data-source';

jest.mock( 'axios' );

test( 'Aggregation page loads all components.', async () => {
    global.tlsAggregationPage = {
        id: 123,
        resultUrl: 'test',
    };

    axios.get.mockResolvedValue( { data: aggregationData } );
```

I've tried to mock the response for `ajaxGet` but I'm at a dead end. How can I mock the value which is passed to `defaultConfig.success( JSON.parse( httpRequest.responseText ) );`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the unit test solution:

`_utility.js`:

```js
export const ajaxGet = (config) => {
  const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const defaultConfig = Object.assign(
    {
      url: '',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: (response) => {},
    },
    config,
  );

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status >= 200 && httpRequest.status < 300) {
        defaultConfig.success(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText));
      }
    }
  };

  httpRequest.open('GET', defaultConfig.url, true);
  httpRequest.send();
};
```

`AggregationPageContent.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ajaxGet } from './_utility';

const tlsAggregationPage = { restUrl: 'https://example.com', termId: '1' };

export class AggregationPageContent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: false,
      page: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { restUrl, termId } = tlsAggregationPage;

    ajaxGet({
      url: `${restUrl}/category/${termId}?page=${this.state.page}`,
      success: (response) => {
        this.setState({
          data: response,
          page: 1,
        });
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

`AggregationPage.test.jsx`:

```js
import { AggregationPageContent } from './AggregationPageContent';
import { ajaxGet } from './_utility';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

jest.mock('./_utility.js', () => {
  return {
    ajaxGet: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('AggregationPageContent', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    let successCallback;
    ajaxGet.mockImplementationOnce(({ url, success }) => {
      successCallback = success;
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<AggregationPageContent></AggregationPageContent>);
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy();
    const mResponse = [];
    successCallback(mResponse);
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ data: [], page: 1 });
    expect(ajaxGet).toBeCalledWith({ url: 'https://example.com/category/1?page=0', success: successCallback });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59299691/AggregationPage.test.jsx (13.603s)
  AggregationPageContent
    ✓ should pass (13ms)

----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 AggregationPageContent.jsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.403s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59299691